# In Nextjs, how to extract what's in the location bar?

Tags: authentication, next.js, strapi, google-signin

I'm following [this guide](https://www.manuelkruisz.com/blog/posts/strapi-react-google-authentication-provider) to learn how to implement a **Login with Google** button (along with the help of [Strapi](https://strapi.io). The guide works fine with Reactjs.

A **problem** occurs when I try to do the same thing with Nextjs with this part of the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

function GoogleAuthCallback() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState()
  const location = useLocation()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!location) {
      return
    }
    const { search } = location
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `http://localhost:1337/auth/google/callback?${search}`,
    })
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .then(setAuth)
  }, [location])

  return (
    <div>
      {auth && (
        <>
          <div>Jwt: {auth.jwt}</div>
          <div>User Id: {auth.user.id}</div>
          <div>Provider: {auth.user.provider}</div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default GoogleAuthCallback
```

I get the following error:
[image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined]

**Question: is there someway to extract what's in the location bar in Nextjs because `useLocation()` is not working.

Thanks!

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router, https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Comment: Next.js has its own [built-in router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), you should use that instead of `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `useLocation()` try to access `window.location`, that is not defined in SSR.
You should import your component dynamically with SSR disabled :
for example in your page :

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/GoogleAuthCallback'), // <- path of your component
  { ssr: false } 
)
```

Please note that  you can also use default [next.js router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) :

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
function GoogleAuthCallback() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState()
   const router = useRouter()
   const location = router.pathname // or router.asPath
  ....
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the next.js router. Finally got this thing working. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply you have to use router instead of location to update your component eg:

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router"
const router = useRouter();
useEffect(() => {'something happened here'},[router])
```